# On page refresh my stored procedure doubles the items displayed in my view

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

Sql Server 2014, MVC 4 Web Service method, Json data, calling a stored procedure that, upon page refresh doubles my data count in the view. Duplicates. Keeps going
 with every page refresh.

Query:

```
        ALTER PROCEDURE spGetPricing
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO Pricing_Compare (ProductID,SKU,ScansourcePrice,BluestarPrice,BarcodePrice,Manufacturer,Product)    
SELECT Product.ProductID,Product.SKU,Scansource.COST, Bluestar.PRICE, ProductVariant.Price, Manufacturer.Name,Product.Name
FROM Product 
INNER JOIN Scansource ON Product.SKU =Scansource.SKU
INNER JOIN Bluestar ON Product.SKU = Bluestar.MFG_PART_NUMBER
INNER JOIN ProductVariant ON Product.ProductID = ProductVariant.ProductID 
INNER JOIN ProductManufacturer ON Product.ProductID = ProductManufacturer.ProductID 
INNER JOIN Manufacturer ON ProductManufacturer.ManufacturerID = Manufacturer.ManufacturerID

SELECT * FROM Pricing_Compare

END
```

C# code:

```
using CSVTool.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace CSVTool
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for PricingService
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
     [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class PricingService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
        [WebMethod]
        public void GetPricing()
        {
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            List<PricingModel> pricingModel = new List<PricingModel>();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetPricing", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    PricingModel pricinglist = new PricingModel();
                    pricinglist.Manufacturer = rdr["Manufacturer"].ToString();
                    pricinglist.Product = rdr["Product"].ToString();
                    pricinglist.SKU = rdr["SKU"].ToString();
                    pricinglist.BarcodePrice = rdr["BarcodePrice"].ToString();
                    pricinglist.ScansourcePrice = rdr["ScansourcePrice"].ToString();
                    pricinglist.BluestarPrice = rdr["BluestarPrice"].ToString();
                    pricingModel.Add(pricinglist);
                }
            }
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer(); js.MaxJsonLength = 2147483644;
            Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(pricingModel));
        }
    }
}
```

I have 2 other views that don't behave like that but the stored procedure is simply a select, not the accompanying insert and joins. Is there a way to change the stored procedure so that everytime I load the page it doesn't load a fresh set of duplicates? In the query or on the client side(in my web service method)?

Comment: Um - your stored procedure performs an insert into the table, and then selects from it.  Am I missing something here?  Why do you even need the `Pricing_Compare` table?  Just execute the select as you have it.

Comment: @BrendanGreen The table is empty until I fill it with data from the joins. I don't know how to load the table seperately so I combined the joins and the select into one sp. How can I get the data into Pricing_Compare and select it without including the joins in the stored proc?

Comment: Right.  So, the first time the SP executes, the `Pricing_Compare` table is empty.  It gets populated, and then you select the data from it.  Now, the next time that the SP gets executed, it **re inserts** all the data into `Pricing_Compare` again, and then selects from it.  Why worry about populating `Pricing_Compare` then?  Just return the data from your select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that every time you execute your stored procedure, you're inserting data into `Pricing_Compare` first, and then selecting from it.

That means, for every execution of the stored procedure, you are adding (potentially) duplicate records into `Pricing_Compare`.

There is no need to populate this table at all - just return the data as such:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spGetPricing
AS
BEGIN

SELECT 
    Product.ProductID,
    Product.SKU,
    Scansource.COST, 
    Bluestar.PRICE, 
    ProductVariant.Price, 
    Manufacturer.Name,
    Product.Name AS ProductName
FROM 
    Product 
INNER JOIN 
    Scansource 
ON 
    Product.SKU =Scansource.SKU
INNER JOIN 
    Bluestar 
ON 
    Product.SKU = Bluestar.MFG_PART_NUMBER
INNER JOIN 
    ProductVariant 
ON 
    Product.ProductID = ProductVariant.ProductID 
INNER JOIN 
    ProductManufacturer 
ON 
    Product.ProductID = ProductManufacturer.ProductID 
INNER JOIN 
    Manufacturer 
ON 
    ProductManufacturer.ManufacturerID = Manufacturer.ManufacturerID

END
```

Comment: Thank you!!! That worked perfectly. But I had to do Product.Name AS ProductName and give it that alias because there were 2 columns named Name. Thanks Brendan.

Comment: Consider turning this into a view instead of a stored procedure